# If $f_n : X \to \mathbb C$ converges to $f: X \to \mathbb C$ in $1$-norm then $\log |f_n|$ converges to $\log |f|$ in $1$-norm

Tags: measure-theory

Here's the question that I have.
Let $X,\mu$ be a probability measure space. If $f_n : X \to \mathbb C$ converges to $f: X \to \mathbb C$ in $1$-norm and suppose that for some $\epsilon > 0$, $|f_n| \ge \varepsilon$ and $|f| \ge \epsilon$ on $X$ then $\log |f_n|$ converges to $\log |f|$ in $1$-norm.

I'm not sure if my claim is true. Here's my attempt: Observe that
\begin{align*}
\exp \left( \int_{X} \lvert \log |f_n| - \log |f|  \rvert d\mu \right) &= \exp \left( \int_{X} \log \left\lvert \frac{f_n}{f} \right\rvert d\mu \right) \\
&\le \int_{X} \frac{|f_n|}{|f|} d\mu \\
& \le  \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_X |f_n| d\mu.
\end{align*}

The second inequality is due to Jensen's inequality. I can take log both sides but I do not how to proceed anymore. Hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Mean Value Theorem for logarithm $|\log |f_n|-\log |f\|| \leq \frac 1 {\epsilon}||f_n|-|f||\leq \frac 1 {\epsilon}|f_n-f|$.